# Facebook messenger bot scheduled messages using Serverless and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, message-queue, serverless-framework, facebook-messenger-bot

I am planning to create a Facebook messenger bot which sends scheduled messages based on user input time. Eg: If User selects 6 AM then I need to send him some message in this time daily.

Now I have created a basic messenger bot with help of serverless. I am stuck with this scheduled messages part. My question is: what are the basic things I need to take care for this? Do I need a queuing system for this like AWS SQS and CloudFront event scheduler? I don't have prior experience with these services. But I pretty much want to stay with in AWS land.

Could you guys point me towards a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, your Facebook bot would receive the user input (6 AM) and it would need to request the backend (a Lambda function) to schedule some operation for this time. At 6 AM, another Lambda function would be triggered to execute the task for this user.

I see that you have tagged this question with the Serverless Framework. It does support scheduling Lambda functions ([docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/)) like in this example:

```
functions:
  doSomething:
    handler: doSomething
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 6 * * ? *) # Set to trigger at 6 AM
```

But currently you can't call the Serverless Framework programatically. You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1678) and [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/2444).

In this case, I guess that you would need to use the [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) to configure and schedule Lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

- SNS messages can't be delayed
- SQS messages can only be delayed for ~15 minutes unless you mess about with message visibility (not recommended in this case)

Your best bet would be to expose CRUD functions so your bot can manage users' schedules into AWS.

Those functions will store schedule records in DynamoDB or whatever persistence strategy you choose.

Then, have a separate function on a cron schedule that periodically scans the schedule records and spawns messages to whatever other function sends the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [CloudWatch scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)? They can be created programmatically and can have cron expressions. You can configure them to trigger lambdas or publish to a stream. It seems that this might be exactly what you need. Be sure to check CloudWatch [limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html) though.